# Django forms taking pre-set value of submit button and not user input

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I have two Django forms on one page, i seperate them like this:

```
if request.method == "POST" and "bid" in request.POST:

    form1 = NewBidForm(request.POST)
    
    if form1.is_valid():
        # Makes sure the big is higher than the previous highest bid
        if float(request.POST["bid"]) > listing.startingbid:
            # Saves bidding to database
            bidding = form1.cleaned_data["bid"]
            newbid = Bid(bid=bidding, user=request.user, listing=listing)
            newbid.save()
            listing.startingbid = bidding
            listing.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("listing", args=[name]))
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'This bid is not higher than the previous bid, try again!')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("listing", args=[name]))
    # If the form is not valid, return user to the original listing page
    else:
        return render(request, "auctions/listing.html", {
            "listing": listing,
            "comments": comments,
            "bids": bids,
            "highestbid": highestbid,
            "bidform": NewBidForm(),
            "commentform": NewCommentForm()
        })

    # Handles user input for user placing a comment on a listing
elif request.method == "POST" and "comment" in request.POST:

    form2 = NewCommentForm(request.POST)
    print(form2)

    if form2.is_valid():
        # Saves comment to database
        comment = form2.cleaned_data["comment"]
        newcomment = Comment(comment=comment, user=request.user, listing=listing)
        newcomment.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("listing", args=[name]))
    else:
        return render(request, "auctions/listing.html", {
            "listing": listing,
            "comments": comments,
            "bids": bids,
            "highestbid": highestbid,
            "bidform": NewBidForm(),
            "commentform": NewCommentForm()
            })
```

The forms look like this:

```
class NewBidForm(forms.Form):
    bid = forms.DecimalField(label="bid", decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)

class NewCommentForm(forms.Form):
    comment = forms.CharField(label="comment", widget=forms.Textarea)
```

and my HTML looks like this:

```
        <form action="{% url 'listing' listing.title %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ bidform }}
            <input type="submit", name="bid", value="Place Bid">
        </form>

        <form action="{% url 'listing' listing.title %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ commentform }}
            <input type="submit", name="comment", value="Place Comment">
        </form>
```

The problem however is that the value i get from both forms is the value on the buttons `<input>`, respectively "Place Bid" and "Place Comment". Why is this and how do i get the actual user input from the form instead?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!
If there's any more info needed, please comment and let me know!

Comment: Remove the `name` attribute from your input buttons. It replaces the value of the field defined in the actual field.

Comment: @jacksparrow92 That fixed it! Perfect thank you. I thought that wouldn't work because of my if statements, but it works perfectly.